# Rotating an object 45 degrees on specified onkeydown

Tags: javascript, rotation, webkit

I have been working on a game project for a while and have hit a snag with a particular control. I have decided to change some of the mechanics a bit to deal with this. I had written a chunk of code to make an object rotate with my mouse movement but now I need to make my object rotate on keypress.

I want to make it rotate 45 degrees clockwise when I press the right arrow key, and 45 degrees counter clockwise on left arrow key press. I have the input key call all written up I just need to translate my old code to the new code.

This is my existing code

```
window.onmouseclick = function(event) {
var box = hypeDocument.getElementById('bolt')
cx = event.pageX; // Mouse X
cy = event.pageY; // Mouse Y
bx = parseInt(hypeDocument.getElementById('group').style.left);
by = parseInt(hypeDocument.getElementById('group').style.top);
tx = hypeDocument.getElementProperty(box, 'left') + 
(hypeDocument.getElementProperty(box, 'width')/2) + bx;
ty = hypeDocument.getElementProperty(box, 'top') + 
(hypeDocument.getElementProperty(box, 'height')/2) + by;


angle = Math.atan2((cy-ty),(cx-tx)) * (180/Math.PI) ; // AHHHH MATH!
hypeDocument.setElementProperty(box, 'rotateZ', angle)
}


hypeDocument.setElementProperty(box, 'rotateZ', angle) // hype api code for

box.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
box.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
box.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
```

This is the code I want to change, as I state in the comment the last line is hype api for the 3 box styles below it to help anybody who reads this understand what that line is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the hypedocument markup, but I put this together for you. Can you extract the meaningful parts re: the keycodes to make it work with your project?

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode,
      dir = '',
      box = document.getElementById('box');
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    dir = 'left';
  } else if (keyCode == 37) {
    dir = 'right';
  }
  box.setAttribute('data-dir','');
  setTimeout(function() {
    box.setAttribute('data-dir',dir);
  })
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

[data-dir="left"] {
  animation: left .5s forwards; 
}

[data-dir="right"] {
  animation: right .5s forwards; 
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  to {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```